# How do I find a rooms avilabilty from followind database

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Table for room booking

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rooms]
(    
    [room_no] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [cust_id] [varchar](5)  NOT NULL,
    [check_in_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [check_out_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [no_of_rooms] [int] NOT NULL,
    [no_of_members] [int] NOT NULL,
    [room_type] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [room_status] [varchar](50)  NOT NULL,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The query:

```
declare @dateforbooking datetime
declare @room_no varchar

set @dateforbooking = '2012-02-26 11:00'
set @room_no = 1

select 
    * 
from rooms 
where 
    room_no = @room_no
    and @dateforbooking between check_in_date and check_out_date
```

The @room_no var indicates the room number you're after, the @dateforbooking is the datetime you wish to book the room for, if the room is already booked, the query will return the row of the booking, if there are no bookings during that time for that room, the resulset will be empty.